# detecting isolated voxel-blob in 3D cube with breadth first search

Tags: c#, unity3d

I just recently got into c# and Unity coding, and would like to put this algorithm and code up for review to check how I'm doing. I've only been working by myself, so it would be interesting to hear how my code design and style could be improved.
The task is like so:

There's a 3D cubical grid (`stateGrid`) containing voxels that are either 1 or 0. It is stored as a flattened array. If multiple 1-voxels are neighboring eachother, they form an island together.

I want to detect islands smaller than a given size (`blobMin`), and convert those to 0's. The function returns the voxels that are part of islands up for deletion.

Checking if voxel is in an island is implemented with a breadth-first-search within the Walker function.

Performance is quite important, since the cube can be of size 64 or even bigger, and I think there's a bunch to gain still algorithmically.

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class IslandRemove{
    private int mapSize;
    private int mapCubeSize;
    private float[] state;
    private float[] result;
    private int index;
    private int connectCount;
    private int blobMin;

    private HashSet<Vector3Int> history;
    private Queue<Vector3Int> queue;
    private int blobSz;


    public IslandRemove(int mapSize, int mapCubeSize, int blobMin){
        this.mapSize = mapSize;
        this.mapCubeSize = mapCubeSize;
        this.blobMin = blobMin;
        result = new float[mapCubeSize];
    }

    private int getIdx(Vector3Int v){
        return v.z * mapSize * mapSize + v.y * mapSize + v.x;
    }

    private void ProcessNode(Vector3Int newVect){
        // if not already in history
        if (!history.Contains(newVect)){
            blobSz++;
            // add node to queue for later check
            queue.Enqueue(newVect);
            // mark node as counted so we don't count again, or check its connections
            history.Add(newVect);
        }
    }

    private bool walker(int x, int y, int z){

        blobSz = 0;
        queue = new Queue<Vector3Int>();
        history = new HashSet<Vector3Int>();
        ProcessNode(new Vector3Int(x, y, z)); // queue start position
        var loopcount = 0;

        while (blobSz < blobMin){
            loopcount++;
            var node = queue.Dequeue();
            var idx = getIdx(node);

            // check edges
            if (node.x != 0){ // edge x-
                if ((int)state[idx - 1] == 1)
                    ProcessNode(new Vector3Int(node.x - 1, node.y, node.z));
            }
            if (node.x != mapSize - 1){ // edge x+
                if ((int) state[idx + 1] == 1)
                    ProcessNode(new Vector3Int(node.x + 1, node.y, node.z));
            }
            if (node.y != 0){ // edge y-
                if ((int) state[idx - mapSize] == 1)
                    ProcessNode(new Vector3Int(node.x, node.y-1, node.z));
            }
            if (node.y != mapSize - 1){ // edge y+
                if ((int) state[idx + mapSize] == 1)
                    ProcessNode(new Vector3Int(node.x, node.y+1, node.z));
            }
            if (node.z != 0){ // edge z-
                if ((int) state[idx - mapSize*mapSize] == 1){
                    ProcessNode(new Vector3Int(node.x, node.y, node.z-1));           
                }
            }
            if (node.z != mapSize - 1){ // edge z+
                if ((int) state[idx + mapSize*mapSize] == 1)
                    ProcessNode(new Vector3Int(node.x, node.y, node.z+1));
            }

            if (queue.Count == 0){
                return true; // add to removelist
            }
        }
        return false; // target is reached, don't add to removelist
    }

    public List<Vector3Int> IslandRemover(float[] stateGrid){
        state = stateGrid;
        var remove = new List<Vector3Int>();
        var removeThis = false;
        var lastOneWasOne = false; // start with false
        // iterate through cube
        for (int z = 0; z < mapSize; z++){
            for (int y = 0; y < mapSize; y++){
                for (int x = 0; x < mapSize; x++){
                    var idx = z * mapSize * mapSize + y * mapSize + x;
                    if ((int) state[idx] == 1 && !lastOneWasOne){ 
                        removeThis = walker(x, y, z);
                        if (removeThis)
                            remove.Add(new Vector3Int(x,y,z));
                        else{
                            lastOneWasOne = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        lastOneWasOne = false;
                    }

                    if ((int)state[idx] == 0){
                        lastOneWasOne = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return remove;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> private int mapSize;
> private int mapCubeSize;
> private float[] state;
> private float[] result;
> private int index;
> private int connectCount;
> private int blobMin;
> ```

You should clean up unused members: `mapCubeSize`, `result`, `index` and `connectCount` are unused.

---

Be consistent with your naming: methods and properties of a class are named with `PascalCase`, while fields are named with `camelCase` (e.g. `walker()` should be `Walker()` (BTW: `walker()` is a strange and mysterious name saying nothing about its behavior))

---

> ```
> private HashSet<Vector3Int> history;
> private Queue<Vector3Int> queue;
> private int blobSz;
> ```

These members represent partial states inside `walker()`. I don't like them to be class members. Instead you could provide them as parameters to `ProcessNode()`, or you could define `ProcessNode()` as a nested method inside `walker()`:

```
private bool walker(int x, int y, int z)
{

  int blobSz = 0;
  Queue<Vector3Int> queue = new Queue<Vector3Int>();
  HashSet<Vector3Int> history = new HashSet<Vector3Int>();
  ProcessNode(new Vector3Int(x, y, z)); // queue start position
  var loopcount = 0;

  void ProcessNode(Vector3Int newVect)
  {
    // if not already in history
    if (!history.Contains(newVect))
    {
      blobSz++;
      // add node to queue for later check
      queue.Enqueue(newVect);
      // mark node as counted so we don't count again, or check its connections
      history.Add(newVect);
    }
  }

  while (blobSz < blobMin)
  {
    loopcount++;
    var node = queue.Dequeue();
    var idx = getIdx(node);
    ...
```

---

> ```
> private void ProcessNode(Vector3Int newVect){
>     // if not already in history
>     if (!history.Contains(newVect)){
>         blobSz++;
>         // add node to queue for later check
>         queue.Enqueue(newVect);
>         // mark node as counted so we don't count again, or check its connections
>         history.Add(newVect);
>     }
> }
> ```

The `HashSet<T>.Add()` method returns a `bool` indicating if the value was added (`true`) or already present. You can use that to simplify `ProcessNode()`:

```
  void ProcessNode(Vector3Int newVect)
  {
    // if not already in history
    if (history.Add(newVect))
    {
      blobSz++;
      // add node to queue for later check
      queue.Enqueue(newVect);
    }
  }
```

---

All the calls to `ProcessNode()` creates a new `Vector3Int` instance from coordinates (x, y, z). Consider to change its signature to: `ProcessNode(int x, int y, int z)` and then create the vector inside `ProcessNode(...)` instead:

```
ProcessNode(int x, int y, int z)
{
  newVect = new Vector3Int(x, y, z);
  ...
}
```

---

Instead of this:

> ```
>     // check edges
>     if (node.x != 0)
>     { // edge x-
>       if ((int)state[idx - 1] == 1)
>         ProcessNode(new Vector3Int(node.x - 1, node.y, node.z));
>     }
> ```

I think, I would prefer:

```
    // check edges (x-)
    if (node.x != 0 && (int)state[idx - 1] == 1)
    { 
      ProcessNode(new Vector3Int(node.x - 1, node.y, node.z));
    }
```

---

> ```
>       removeThis = walker(x, y, z);
>       if (removeThis)
> ```

You only use `removeThis` once, so no need to define it as a variable:

```
if (walker(x, y, z))
   ...
```

is clear enough.

Comment: Woah, I learned a lot! Also gained a speedup it seems, maybe because of not creating so many Vector3Int() variables after changing to ProcessNode(int x, int y, int z). Many thanks